# php - & в аргументах функции

Tags: php

Объясните, пожалуйста, что означает запись аргумента в функции:

```
function somefunc(&$somevar){...}
```

Comment: Передача по ссылке?

Comment: & с переменной = передача по ссылке?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.by-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это [передача по ссылке](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.references.pass.php).
Вы можете передавать переменные в функцию по ссылке, и функция сможет изменять свои аргументы.
Пример:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function test($a, &$b){
  $a++;
  $b++;
}

test($a, $b);
var_dump($a, $b); // int(1) int(3)
```

https://repl.it/IOxg/0